# Is there any way to set OTP based authentication for some of the guests accounts in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to set OTP-based authentication for some of the guest's accounts in Azure AD? I don't want this feature enabled for all guest users.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Email one-time passcode authentication(OTP based) can be enabled only for all the guests in Azure AD.

It is not possible to limit usage of Email one-time passcode authentication for a group of guest users or Azure AD groups.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/one-time-passcode